# function which does not work well

Tags: php, exit

I have php function which does not work well:

```
public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
    {
        require_once Mage::getModuleDir('', 'Spectrocoin_Spectrocoin') . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'SCMerchantClient' . DS . 'SCMerchantClient.php';
        $privateKeyFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/spectrocoin/keys/' . Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/Spectrocoin/private_key_file');
        $merchantId = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/Spectrocoin/merchant_id');
        $appId = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/Spectrocoin/app_id');
        if (!file_exists($privateKeyFilePath) || !is_file($privateKeyFilePath)
            || !$merchantId || !$appId) {
            echo 'Spectrocoin is not fully configured. Please select different payment';
            exit;
        }
```

And until `if` I think everything is good because if i paste exit somewhere until `if` it works but after `if` nothing works I tried exit, print didnt help....

Comment: There is some function error logs or something like that, but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Any error that you are getting..Please attach the error logs also

Comment: that is problem i don't get any errors in logs.

Comment: Does it show the echo text?